# datagridview multiple criteria filtering

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am developping an WinForms software with a datagridview, three textboxes, a combobox and a search_button to filter data in the gridview depending on what users fill in the input fields. My question here is how to write in the button click event a unique query to filter the gridview with the criterias of the textboxes and the combobox ?

Comment: You can filter the DataSource through RowFilter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). It has a SQL-like format which can easily deliver the functionality you want. Hopefully this will be enough, because this question is offtopic.

Comment: It depends of the data source used. So what's yours - `DataTable`, `List`, `BindingList` etc. ?